# How to configure Redis as cache in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I am new to Redis trying to use Redis for caching. What all dependencies should be there and what all gems should be there.

Answer (score 0):

We can use redis in rails for multiple purposes if u just want to use for caching you follow this guide :

https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-model-caching-redis/